# Is it Possible to mount windows partition on Linux automatically when system starts?

Tags: windows-7, debian, mount, multi-boot, automount

I have a Dualbooted PC, windows 7 64 bit  and a Debian wheezy distro, I have all my music and documents on windows. When on Linux I have to manually mount windows filesystem partition on Linux.

This isn't very convenient, for example, if you listen to music on linux, you have to keep mounting your windows partition every time you login, and import your library and so on. If you organize your PDF using a software, you have to keep importing them, et cetera.

So is it Possible to mount windows partition on Linux automatically when system starts? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, add it to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdN# /media/windows ntfs 0 0
```

You will need to determine which disk (N) and partiton (#) windows is on.

Assuming you have an MBR disk, you can determine with `N` and `#` to use with `fdisk -l`, find your windows partition and use that.  Of course, you may need to make the directory to mount to (`sudo mkdir /media/name`).